# How to add current time stamp into image path

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

I'm trying to add current time stamp into image path in php and store the image path into MySQL. I've searched from google and saw `insert_time=now()`. I trying to code but I get error in my php.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){

            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";

            $image = $_POST['image'];

            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 

            $sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";

            $id=1;

            $res=$mysqli->query( $sql );
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $id=$rs->id;

            $path=NOW()."$id.png";
            $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";

            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );

            $pathelements=array( realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ), 'CRUD', 'PhotoUpload', '' );
            $savepath = realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathelements ) ) . "{$id}.png";

            $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $image ) );
            if( !$bytes ){
                echo 'Error saving image';  
            }

            if ( $stmt && $bytes) {
                 foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 

                    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $item['type'], $item['amount'], $item['description'], $actualpath, $item['ts_id'] );
                    $res=$stmt->execute();

                    if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

**Error**

```
call to undefined function Now()
```

It seems like the Now() is not existing :( .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function now()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992760/call-to-undefined-function-now)

Comment: I'm curious why people here like to close people question ? You may mark my question as duplicated but no need to vote to close question :) And the link provided doesn't help some more :)

Comment: If you are earnestly asking, try https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ -- I could not quickly find a question precisely about why, but this one covers that (and a lot more): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: @tripleee ok, thanks sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
$path=date("mdYHis")."$id.png";
```

instead of `$path=NOW()."$id.png";`

Comment: `011420160726511` In front is today date, how about 0726511?

Comment: that was hour, minute and seconds..  u can use this to be sure of no duplicate value basically for the precision..   you could only use upto `date('mdY')` if u want to. that will give you `01142016`

Comment: I'm trying to store 3 image path to mysql at the same time(by arraylist). But when I check , it has 3 records, but 3 image is from the first image...do you know why ?

Comment: because your `$actualpath` has a single value all the time you should put the whole thing in the while loop.

Comment: I thought the $id will auto-increment ?

Comment: yes it will autoincrement but the rest of the code is not in your that while loop scope

Comment: It is while loop  `while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() )` ?

Comment: the text can be inserted, just the image path are the same. When I open the folder, I only see one image there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100637/discussion-between-pritam-jinal-and-tony).

Answer (score 3):

You were using Sql function earlier. That was the problem. Try this as per your requirement.

```
 $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["p_image"]["name"]);
    $image_path = $path_parts['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$path_parts['extension']
```

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` is a SQL function but not a PHP function. You probably want the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Modify this line

```
 $path=NOW()."$id.png";
```

to

```
 $path=time()"$id.png";
```